# Ruby array iteration with .each fails to fetch elements returning only one element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I have a class 'Service' which implements an enum for

```
Service.statuses => `{"authorization_pending"=>"authorization_pending",
                      "provider_assignment_pending"=>"provider_assignment_pending",
                      "user_contact_pending"=>"user_contact_pending",
                      "first_visit_pending"=>"first_visit_pending",
                      "budget_pending"=>"budget_pending",
                      "budget_review_pending"=>"budget_review_pending",
                      "acceptance_budget_pending"=>"acceptance_budget_pending",
                      "finalizing_pending"=>"finalizing_pending",
                      "documentation_pending"=>"documentation_pending",
                      "review_pending"=>"review_pending",
                      "rejected"=>"rejected",
                      "completed"=>"completed",
                      "on_hold"=>"on_hold"}
```

I need to iterate though each status to build FactoryBot instances of a Service with each status, (I'm using FactoryBot to seed the development database) so I do this: `

```
status_collection = Service.statuses.keys.map {|stat| stat.to_sym }` => 
 [:authorization_pending,
  :provider_assignment_pending,
  :user_contact_pending,
  :first_visit_pending,
  :budget_pending,
  :budget_review_pending,
  :acceptance_budget_pending,
  :finalizing_pending,
  :documentation_pending,
  :review_pending,
  :rejected,
  :completed,
  :on_hold]
```

and then to iterate through the symbols array:

```
status_collection.each do |stts|
  FactoryBot.create(:service, stts, <other attributes not relevant>).tap {|serv| puts serv.status }
end
```

`FactoryBot.create` second argument is to call upon a Factory 'trait' that used in isolation returns the desired result of creating a Service in the proper status.
The tap statement is only for showing the resulting record status. The problem that baffles me is that after the second iteration, the result is producing Service records only for the second element of 'status_collection´, namely: ':provider_assignment_pending'.

Here is the Factory code:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :service, class: 'Service' do
    description       { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }
    facility_manager  { association(:operator) }
    network_manager   { association(:operator) }
    service_type      { association(:service_type) }
    space             { association(:space) }
    user              { association(:user) }

    trait :authorization_pending do
      provider { association(:provider) }
    end
    trait :provider_assignment_pending do
      provider { association(:provider) }
    end

    trait :user_contact_pending do
      provider { association(:provider) }
    end

    trait :first_visit_pending do
      user_contact_pending
      visits { [association(:visit, service: instance)] }
    end

    trait :budget_pending do
      first_visit_pending
      visits { [association(:visit, :finished, service: instance)] }
      budgets { [association(:budget, :created, service: instance)] }
    end

    trait :budget_review_pending do
      budget_pending
      budgets { [association(:budget, :operator_reviewing, service: instance)] }
    end

    trait :acceptance_budget_pending do
      budget_pending
      budgets { [association(:budget, :client_reviewing, service: instance)] }
    end

    trait :finalizing_pending do
      budget_pending
      budgets { [association(:budget, :selected, service: instance)] }
    end

    trait :review_pending do
      finalizing_pending
      service_completions { [association(:service_completion, service: instance)] }
    end

    trait :rejected do
      provider { association(:provider) }
    end

    trait :completed do
      visits { [association(:visit, :finished, service: instance)] }
      budgets { [association(:budget, :created, service: instance)] }
      service_completions { [association(:service_completion, service: instance)] }
    end

    trait :on_hold do
      review_pending
    end

    trait :documentation_pending do
      completed
    end
  end
end
```

My question (and cry for help) is what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why does your enum have have strings as keys?

Comment: Probably the "<other attributes not relevant>" might be relevant? The rest of the "visible" code seems fine. How did you define the enum?

Comment: Is there any chance that `Service` prevents setting its state to something else based on its other attributes or previous states?

Comment: Please post the model and the factory. Also please note that your screenshot is unlikely to be relevant given that the development environment and the test environment are completely separate.

Comment: @max I am working with a legacy app... So the enum was already defined like ´enum status: %i[authorization_pending provider_assignment_pending user_contact_pending first_visit_pending budget_pending
                  budget_review_pending acceptance_budget_pending finalizing_pending documentation_pending review_pending rejected
                  completed on_hold].to_enum_hash´

Comment: The 'Service' model is 628 lines long... It may be too much to include here, and yes, it is full of relations with other tables, scopes and virtual attributes that may cause the issue with FactoryBot, I will edit the question to include the Factory...

Comment: Well I guess you could replace the wonky monkeypatch  `to_enum_hash` with `.then { |ary| ary.zip(ary.map(&:to_s)).to_h }` but that will very likely break parts of the app that built around this weird setup.

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext as [they are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). Please copy and paste plaintext into your question.

Answer (score 0):

My team leader (Javier) gave me the solution for this: FactoryBot usually uses any enum defined in the model as an automatic trait for the factory, unless you define those traits with special code, as I am doing with the status enum, then you should include the enum attribute specifically, as in

```
trait :review_pending do
      finalizing_pending
      status { :review_pending }
      service_completions { [association(:service_completion, service: instance)] }
end
```

Thanks to everybody